# PL/SQL date or to_char question

Tags: oracle, plsql, date

```
     begin
     if TO_CHAR('23-OCT-1994','DAY') = 'FRIDAY' THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FRIDAY');
     else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not Friday');
     end if;
     end;
     /
```

I am trying to see if 10/23/1994 is Friday.
If it is Friday, it is going to return FRI, if not, NOT FRI

However I get
"PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error".

Answer (score 1):

`'23-OCT-1994'` is a string, not a `DATE`, so `TO_CHAR` on a character is pointless.

First you have to convert your string into a `DATE` value. You should specify the date format plus the language which is used:

```
TO_DATE('23-OCT-1994', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
```

Then you can compare with your weekday. Note, `'DAY'` returns the weekday but padded with spaces up to the longest name. Try `'"'||TO_CHAR(DATE '2018-10-23', 'DAY')||'"'` to see the effect. You should also specify the language.

You can use one of the following:

- `TRIM(TO_CHAR(..., 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')) = 'FRIDAY'`
- `TO_CHAR(..., 'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 'FRIDAY'`
- `TO_CHAR(..., 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 'FRI'`

for example

```
begin
   if TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('23-OCT-1994', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'),'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 'FRIDAY' THEN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FRIDAY');
   else
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not Friday');
   end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in using the `TO_CHAR` function on a text string which is interpreted as a string, rather than a date. This will throw the same error:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('23-OCT-1994','DAY') FROM dual;
```

Instead, you'll need to use `TO_DATE` to convert the string to a date, then you would be able to use `TO_CHAR` on the output of that.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('23-OCT-1994', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DAY') FROM dual;
```

Rather than doing an `IF` statement with `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()`, you could do this with a simple `SELECT` statement using the `CASE` syntax:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('23-OCT-1994', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DAY') = 'FRIDAY' 
               THEN 'Friday'
          ELSE 'Not Friday'
        END
FROM dual;
```

Comment: The language information is also missing.

Comment: `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('23-OCT-1994', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DAY')` gives `"SUNDAY   "` - not `"SUNDAY"`

Answer (score 0):

TO_CHAR( *DATE DATATYPE* , 'DAY' ) ----> Gives DAY of *DATE DATATYPE*

The TO_CHAR function can extract DAY from DATE datatype. As you are passing STRING as the first parameter, it does not understand it.

Here, is the same using decode. You can very well do with the case or anonymous block.

```
select decode( to_char(to_date('23-OCT-1994', 'dd-MON-yyyy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'), 'DAY')
                , 'FRIDAY'
                , 'Yes Friday'
                , 'No Friday')
          from dual;
```